# How do I view my cookies in Safari 7 Web Inspector?

Tags: safari, cookies

I've got the developer menu enabled, and am looking at the Web Inspector, but the instructions I've been able to find for viewing cookies in Safari 6 don't seem to apply in Safari 7.

How do I view my cookies in the Safari 7 Web Inspector?

Answer (score 2):

Open the inspector with either 
* right clic > Inspect element 
* Menu > Develop > Show Page Ressources

Then select the cookie line in the left menu that appeared on the bottom of your Safari Page.

[image]

Comment: But this is not a complete list of the cookies! What about domain-scoped cookies? Why are these omitted? How can I see those as well?